# Is there a fast running rolling standard deviation algorithm?

Tags: python

I have a Python script in which for every new sample i have to update the standard deviation of this samples array using a rolling window of length N. Using the simple formula of the standard deviation the code is really slow. I found many different solutions for online calculation but all of them are NOT considering a rolling window for the update. Some of alternative way for computing the variance are explained here (Welford algorithm, parallel, ...)
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance
but none of them are actually using a rolling window through data set.
What i'm looking for is a fast algorithm which won't be prone to catastrophic cancellation phenomenon.
Formulas will be appreciated.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: https://jonisalonen.com/2014/efficient-and-accurate-rolling-standard-deviation/

Comment: let array length = m. You could do it in O(m) time by keeping track of rolling means and rolling (xi - mean)^2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an adaptation of the code at the [link I put in a comment](https://jonisalonen.com/2014/efficient-and-accurate-rolling-standard-deviation/). It takes `O(1)` (constant) time for each element added, regardless of window size. Note that if you configure for a window of `N` elements, the first `N-1` results are more-than-less gibberish: it initializes the data to `N` zeroes. The class also saves the most recent `N` entries in a `collections.deque` of maximum size `N`. Note that this computes the "sample" standard deviation, not "population". Season to taste ;-)

```py
from collections import deque
from math import sqrt

class Running:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.data = deque([0.0] * n, maxlen=n)
        self.mean = self.variance = self.sdev = 0.0

    def add(self, x):
        n = self.n
        oldmean = self.mean
        goingaway = self.data[0]
        self.mean = newmean = oldmean + (x - goingaway) / n
        self.data.append(x)
        self.variance += (x - goingaway) * (
            (x - newmean) + (goingaway - oldmean)) / (n - 1)
        self.sdev = sqrt(self.variance)
```

Here's a by-eyeball sanity check. Seems fine. But note that the `statistics` module makes heroic (and slow!) efforts to maximize floating-point accuracy. The code above just accepts accumulating half a dozen fresh rounding errors per element added.

```
import statistics
from random import random
from math import ulp
r = Running(50)
for i in range(1000000):
    r.add(random() * 100)
    assert len(r.data) == 50
    if i % 1000 == 0.0:
        a, b = r.mean, statistics.mean(r.data)
        print(i, "mean", a, b, (a - b) / ulp(b))
        a, b = r.sdev, statistics.stdev(r.data)
        print(i, "sdev", a, b, (a - b) / ulp(b))
```

Sample output (will vary across runs):

```
0 mean 1.4656985567210468 1.4656985567210468 0.0
0 sdev 10.364053886327875 10.364053886327877 -1.0
1000 mean 50.73313401192864 50.73313401192878 -20.0
1000 sdev 31.06576415649153 31.06576415649151 5.0
2000 mean 50.4175663202043 50.41756632020437 -10.0
2000 sdev 27.692406266774878 27.69240626677488 -1.0
3000 mean 53.054435599235525 53.0544355992356 -11.0
3000 sdev 32.439246859431556 32.439246859431606 -7.0
4000 mean 51.66216784517698 51.662167845177 -3.0
4000 sdev 31.026902004950404 31.02690200495047 -18.0
5000 mean 54.08949367166644 54.089493671666425 2.0
5000 sdev 29.405357061221196 29.40535706122128 -24.0
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for. This function is faster than taking a slice (of length N) of an array and calculate the standard deviation with numpy.std(), for example.

Comment: Oh,  yes - and the more data, the relatively more faster it will be.  Glad it helped! If it answered your question, you should mark the answer as "accepted" so it no longer appears to be an open question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

I have a function that I use for standard deviation. I modified it from a php function that calculated standard deviation. You can input an array (or a slice of an array) into it, and it will calculate the standard deviation for that array or slice.

```
def calc_std_dev(lst, precision=0, sample=True):
"""
:param: lst A Python list containing values
:param: precision The number of decimal places desired.
:param: sample Is the data a sample or a population? Set to True by
default.
"""
sum = 0;
length = len(lst)
if length == 0:
    print("The array has zero elements.")
    return false
elif (length == 1) and (sample == True):
    print("The array has only 1 element.")
    return false
else:
    sum = math.fsum(lst)
#  Calculate the arithmetic mean
mean = sum / length
carry = 0.0
for i in lst:
    dev = i - mean
    carry += dev * dev
if sample == True:
    length = length - 1
variance = carry / length
std_dev = math.sqrt(variance)
std_dev = round(std_dev, precision)
return std_dev
```

When I need a rolling standard deviation, I pass in a slice of the total list to calculate the value.